# CRSF protection in Next.js applications

Tags: javascript, cookies, csrf

So, I am trying to add CSRF protection to my Next.js application. I have tried a development branch of the [next-csrf](https://github.com/j0lv3r4/next-csrf) library.
I have a couple of questions though:

1. The library saves the CSRF token as a cookie. Is this secure? Isn't it vulnerable to session hijacks?
2. Shall I refresh the token in every page? If I choose to do so, is there a point in saving the token as a cookie?

In general I am confused on whether the CSRF token should be a cookie or a HTTP header. Also, when shall I generate a new token?

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: I [just wrote](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248385/csrf-double-submit-cookie-pattern-questions/248434#248434) a giant answer about CSRF, but in general: cookies can be used to provide server-stateless anti-CSRF values, but the actual value still needs to be in the body. Or you can use a custom header, in which case the value is usually irrelevant because the ability to set the header at all means the site is trusted.